# Print all rows with a given word in a single column?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file with 8 columns and a few million rows that looks like this:

```
CHR           SNP         BP   A1       TEST    NMISS       BETA         STAT            P 
   1      1:693731     693731    G        ADD      333   -0.02795       -0.365       0.7154
   1      1:693731     693731    G        pc1      333     -1.369       -1.268       0.2058
   1      1:693731     693731    G        pc2      333    -0.2801      -0.2592       0.7957
```

I want to create a new file containing all rows with 'ADD' in the 'TEST' column (column 5). I have tried doing this with awk:

```
awk '$5==ADD' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

This produced a blank text document. How else could this be accomplished? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ADD` is not a variable so you need to quote it:

```
awk '$5=="ADD"' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

or else make it a variable:

```
awk -v var="ADD" '$5==var' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```